# Cache data with user filters in Laravel (and not only)

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Laravel 5.5 + Redis.

Got the following code in controller:

```
$products = Cache::remember('category_'.$category->alias.'_page_'.$page, 1440, function() use ($childrenCategoriesIndexes){
  return Product::whereIn('category_id', $childrenCategoriesIndexes)
                        ->userFilter()
                        ->paginate(15);
});
```

It caches each page. But what if there are too many custom filters? This is `scopeUserFilter()` from `Product` model:

```
public function scopeUserFilter($query) {
        if (request('price_from')) {
            $query->where('price', '>', request('price_from'));
        }
        if (request('price_to')) {
            $query->where('price', '<', request('price_to'));
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

And there're only 2 variables. But what if there will be 10 and more variables, how to cache this data? I think keys like this are not good:

`'category_'.$category->alias.'_page_'.$page.'_'.request('price_from').'_'.request('price_to')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashed the params, then you can include as many as you can:

```
$params = [
    'page' => 1,
    'price_from' => '',
    'price_to' => '',
    'param0' => '',
    ...
];
foreach (array_keys($params) as $param) {
    if (request()->has($param))
        $params[$param] = request()->input($param);
}
$prefix = 'category_';
$hashed = md5(json_encode($params));
$cache_key = $prefix . $hashed;
```

Comment: This is very good solution, thank you! 1 question: how can I set default value to any request() parameter in this case? I used this: `$page= request()->input('page','1');`

Comment: create array with parameter key and its default value, and check against the request if input exists.

Comment: Do this: `$input = request()->only([['page', '1'], 'price_from', 'price_to']);` but there's no `page` variable in `$input` array (checked with `dd($input)`)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

- defining an array of all possible parameters
- looping through that array to check whether the request contains any of those parameters and if so, assigning that value to the relevant key in the array
- creating a hash of the array to use as the key for your cache

...an alternative, and possibly more flexible, approach (which I picked up from [this article](https://laravel-news.com/cache-query-params)) would be to:

- create an array of all request parameters *and sort them alphabetically*
- rebuild the url using this sorted array
- create a hash of this url to use as the key for your cache

This means your code would look something like this:

```
$url = request()->url();
$queryParams = request()->query();

ksort($queryParams);

$queryString = http_build_query($queryParams);

$fullUrl = "{$url}?{$queryString}";

$rememberKey = sha1($fullUrl);

return Cache::remember($rememberKey, $minutes, function () use ($data) {
    return $data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Ben's answer does address how we can cache multiple params, it's not really a good practice to cache all requests.

Caching is typically used for the most popular requests (highly frequent reads, infrequent writes). For example, caching the top 10 param combinations. If you start caching the long tail, you're defeating the purpose of caching as you drift towards more frequent writes and less frequent reads. Eventually you'll run out of memory if you're using in-memory caching engines

I would suggest rethink your caching strategy

Comment: You're right. How to correctly count the most popular queries?

Comment: That depends on the volume and variety of queries. For huge traffic you can use Hadoop mapreduce to parse Nginx/Apache request logs. For medium traffic, DB or caching (for counts) would be fine. If you're going for caching, use increments